# jquery date picker split into multiple fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the usual Jquery datepicker working fine.  But I want to feed it into a set of selectboxes rather than one textfield.  I have had success feeding it into one select field with a specific format but am unsure how to feed all three into different fields with different formats.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search_startdate").datepicker({showOn: 'button', 
                                     buttonImage: '/images/cal/calendar.gif', 
                                     buttonImageOnly: true, 
                                     minDate: 0, 
                                     maxDate: '+6M +10D', 
                                     showAnim: 'fadeIn',
                                     altField: '#startdate_month', 
                                     altFormat: 'MM',
                                     altField: '#startdate_day',
                                     altFormat: 'dd'});
    //$("#datepicker").datepicker({showOn: 'button', buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true});

});
```

This doesn't work, it works on the last field, but ignores the first.  If I remove the second set of altField and altFormat lines, the first works.

I also tried putting them in a series,

```
altField: '#startdate_month', '#start_day', altFormat: 'MM', 'dd'
```

The problem is the same as here:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/JavaScript/Jquery/Q_24767646.html

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest using your set up with a single alternate field to get the first select, then using an onClose handler to parse the date and fill the other selects.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#search_startdate").datepicker({showOn: 'button', 
                                     buttonImage: '/images/cal/calendar.gif', 
                                     buttonImageOnly: true, 
                                     minDate: 0, 
                                     maxDate: '+6M +10D', 
                                     showAnim: 'fadeIn',
                                     altField: '#startdate_month', 
                                     altFormat: 'MM',
                                     onClose: function(dateText,picker) {
                                                 $('#startdate_day').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
                                              }
                                    });
});
```

Comment: +1 After trying to bring ASP.NET MVC to support the Australian date format, I decided to submit 3 fields: day,month,year. Nice and clean URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is simpler I think:

```
$('#datePickerField').datepicker({
    onClose: function (dateText) {
                var objDate = new Date(dateText);
                $('#year_field').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getFullYear() : '');
                $('#month_field').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getMonth() + 1 : '');
                $('#day_field').val(dateText.length ? objDate.getDate() : '');
            }
});
```

and if you want changes made to day,month,year fields update the main datapicker:

```
$('#year_field,#month_field,#day_field').change(function() {
    $('#datePickerField').datepicker('setDate', new Date(
        parseInt($('#year_field').val(), 10),
        parseInt($('#month_field').val(), 10) - 1,
        parseInt($('#day_field').val(), 10)));
});
```

Comment: Yes, much simpler and cleaner. Saved me much time!

Answer (score 0):

just leaving an answer here for future reference, here's a sample of how i did it:

```
$("#departDate").datepicker({
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {

        // use split() to break down the [MM/DD/YYYY] format
        // populate each into multiple field

        $('#departDateDay').val( selectedDate.split(/\//)[1] ); // day
        $('#departDateMonth').val( selectedDate.split(/\//)[0] ); // month
        $('#departDateYear').val( selectedDate.split(/\//)[2] ); // year
    }
})
```